Usage of もんなんだ in this sentence? What kind of nuance does it give?


よく目にはするが人生を始めて浮かんだ言葉だ。
本当に浮かぶもんなんだ
What kind of nuance is もんなんだ giving in this sentence? The character is love stuck so in the previous page says "I want to become beautiful/attractive"
よく目にはするが人生を始めて浮かんだ言葉だ。is "I often see this, but it's the first time that these words show up for me"
But then I'm a bit stumbled on this second sentence.

本当に浮かぶもんなんだ

One of the possible interpretations I can think of is that he used  浮かぶ  similar to 浮く so it has no relation to the previous sentence and it's more akin "I'm really happy/into them" etc. However, I've only seen it used with 浮く and never 浮かぶ.

For 浮かぶ: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53140/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/67922/7810

It's (言葉が)浮かぶ, followed by ものだ, followed by ん+だ.

The subject of this 浮かぶ is 言葉.
もんだ (ものだ): This has many meanings, but here it's used to express 浮かぶ is a general tendency  or common occurrence based on human nature, etc.

The meanings of ものだ
How to parse 親も辞書を買ってやったかいがあるってもんだ


(な)んだ: You probably know this, the explanatory-の. It's used also when you just discovered something that serves as clarification. You may have seen something like そうなんだ ("Oh is that so!").

Therefore, to translate this very verbosely:

本当に(そんな言葉が)浮かぶ。
Such words really show up in one's mind.
本当に(そんな言葉が)浮かぶもんだ。
It's common/natural for such words to really show up in one's mind.
本当に(そんな言葉が)浮かぶもんなんだ。
(I noticed) it's common/natural for such words to really show up in one's mind (and it explains this situation)!

Of course, this is too wordy, so a natural translation might be something like "Didn't know such words could occur to someone in reality".
